# How to change the page title for the "Review Your Contribution" page in the WP version?

Tags: wordpress, contributions

I've seen a lot of similar questions to this one, but not exactly this question.  When one is directed to https://www.example.com/civicrm/contribute/transact/?_qf_Confirm_display=true&qfKey=CRMContributeControllerContributionabclongstringherexyz, the page title in the  shows as "CIVICRM".  I tried to change this via functions.php with the_title hook, but it replaces every title in the menu as well.  Any suggestions appreciated.

[image: Screenshots of Page Titles - both real and on wpmaster demo site]

Comment: doesn't it shows Contribution page title?

Comment: Can you try to replicate this (the title showing as CIVICRM instead of the public page title) on wpmaster: https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/

Comment: I just tried and it seems to work as expected both with and without a specified public page title.

Comment: @PradeepNayak - the Contribution page does, but we are using the "Use a confirmation page" option, and the confirmation page (which appears after one clicks "Review Your Contribution" displays "CIVICRM" as the page title.

Comment: @LarsSG - can you tell me WHERE you are able to specify / not specify a title for the Review Your Contribution (Confirmation) page?

Comment: @LarsSG - On the wpmaster site, the Contribution page shows "Contribution Page" as the h1 and "Help Support CiviCRM!" as an h2, but then on the Confirmation page it displays "Help Support CiviCRM!" as the h1.

Comment: The confirmation page and first page should have the same title, which is set on the first page of the contribution page configuration (either the title of the public title, if present).

Comment: Can you post a screenshot from wpmaster of what the issue is? I'm not seeing what you're seeing.

Comment: @LarsSG - I've updated the screenshot to reflect both the live application and the wpmaster demo.  I just want to change the h1 of the Confirmation page in my live application.

Comment: Are you using a Shortcode to show the Contribution Page?

Comment: @ChristianWach - Yes, in this case the original developer set up the Donate page using the civicrm shortcode.  Is there an attribute that allows for setting a title?  I didn't see one in documentation.

Comment: In "CiviCRM" --> "Settings", what is your "Shortcode Display Mode" set to? I'm guessing "Legacy Base Page Mode". If so, set it to "Remain in Shortcode Mode".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of figuring out where the "CiviCRM" page title was coming from in the auto-generated output, I was able to set the name of the Contribution > Confirmation page by adding a script in the footer (using the "wp_footer" hook in the child theme's functions.php) that checks the URL for a query string value associated with the Confirmation page ("_qf_Confirm_display") when the page ID is that of the Contribute / Donate page, and if that value is "true," overwrites the h1 and the document title with what I want:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'change_donate_conf_title');
function change_donate_conf_title() {
    if (is_page(10911)) {
        $checkConf = $_GET['_qf_Confirm_display'];
        if ($checkConf === 'true') {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                document.title = 'Review Your Contribution';
                document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = 'Review Your Contribution';
            </script>";
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone else down the road.

Comment: I accepted my own answer here because it allowed me to change the name of ONLY the confirmation page.  However, it is worth noting that Christian's last comment on the OP was valid; the "Shortcode Display Mode" was set to "Legacy Base Page Mode."  Changing that should have passed the Public Name from the Form settings to the Confirmation page.